# Getting a leak window error due to my custom dialog?

Tags: android, dialog

I call dismiss but I still get the error:

```
activity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView that was originally added here
```

followed by this error:

j`ava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{a49b58 V.E...... R....... 0,0-1368,224} not attached to window manager`

This is my custom progress dialog:

```
public class CustomProgressDialog extends ProgressDialog {

    private AnimationDrawable animation;

    public CustomProgressDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.custom_progress_dialog);


        ImageView la = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.animation);
        if (la != null) {

            la.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_progress_dialog_animation);
            animation = (AnimationDrawable) la.getBackground();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        super.show();
        animation.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void dismiss() {
        super.dismiss();
        animation.stop();
    }


    @Override
    public void setOnCancelListener(OnCancelListener listener) {
        super.setOnCancelListener(listener);
        dismiss();
    }
}
```

This is how I implement it within an activity:

```
private void showProgressDialog() {

        customProgressDialog = new CustomProgressDialog(this);
        customProgressDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        customProgressDialog.show();
        //so it cannot be closed by user first one lets back button cancel it
        //customProgressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        customProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        autoProgressShutdown();

    }

    private void hideProgressDialog() {
        pdCanceller.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        if (customProgressDialog != null) {

            customProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

And on login I have this method called to kill any dialogs open:

```
private void takeToHome() {

        hideProgressDialog();

        Intent homeIntent = new Intent(this, MainHome.class);
        homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        startActivity(homeIntent);

        customProgressDialog.dismiss();
        finish();
    }
```

A couple of changes I tried already that failed too, in hideProgress dialog I changed it from .hide() to .dismiss() and then I called it purposefully . dismiss() before finish again to make sure nothing was missed, but the errors persist on switching to home and it crashes sometimes, it gets away with it.

I have the dialog shown when an async task takes place such as login to make sure the user knows it is loading and once it is done the animation stops and it seems to be hidden but on finish it crashes --- now I implement this across the whole app wherever I use an async call and it also, crashes throughout the app. Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong or how I can destroy the dialog before switching to other activities

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try this customProgressDialog is null then only should create an object,As per my thought object created first time then again you try to create the object.Then only this leakage windows error comes and also check 
when dialog is going to be dismissed

```
if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
```

If you want to show a dialog at that tiem to apply this codition.

```
if (dialog != null && !dialog.isShowing()) {
        dialog.show();
    }
```